# Why is my class not returning data from a select?

Tags: python, class, psycopg2

I am learning about classes, and trying to write one to connect and select from my db. Is there a better way to do this or am I just missing a return somewhere? The select data isn't returning.

```
import psycopg2
class MyData():
    def __init__(self, host="10.0.66.60", db="db", user="postgres", password="Secret"):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=db, user=user, password=password)
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def query(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)
            
    def close(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()
    
db = MyData()
db.query("SELECT * FROM detail;")
db.close()
```

Comment: `return self.cur.execute(query)`?

Comment: What happened when you tried using ordinary functions instead of a class to implement the behaviour? Did you see the problem then?

Comment: When I used a function, I did this pretty differently. I used a config file, a database.ini, and loose code to open the connection.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem here... Are you facing any issue? you dont need return for the `query` method because db cursor doesnt return anything, to fetch the data you should go with `db.cur.fetchall()` after running the query.

Comment: Am I facing an issue? Yes, the issue laid out in OP. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any `fetchall()` or `fetch()` calls, which is where the data would be returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import psycopg2
class MyData():
    def __init__(self, host="10.0.66.60", db="db", user="postgres", password="Secret"):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=db, user=user, password=password)
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def query(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)

        # you need fetchall or fetchone to get the data, eg:
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        for row in result:
            print(row)
        # ref: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall
            
    def close(self):
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()
    
db = MyData()
db.query("SELECT * FROM detail;")
db.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot.. Do you see any flaws in the way I am doing my class? Thanks again.